# Making decorator for class method in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I'm founded staff_member_required for function-based views, but didn't find for class methods. Well, I'm tried to write decorator for my class-based view:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.views.generic import View

def cls_method_staff_member_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return staff_member_required(view_func=func)(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class SetUserData(View):
    http_method_names = ['get', ]

    @cls_method_staff_member_decorator
    def get(self, request, user_id):
        # ... some actions with data
```

But after starting server via runserver command, taking error:

> TypeError at /en-us/user/userdata/7/ get() takes exactly 3
>   arguments (2 given)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decorate the `dispatch` method by using the `method_decorator`.

```
class SetUserData(View):
    @method_decorator(cls_method_staff_member_decorator)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SetUserData, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)

Alternatively decorate in `urls`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^your_url/', cls_method_staff_member_decorator(SetUserData.as_view())),
    ...
)
```